# How can I tell if this issue is a virus?

Tags: windows-10, virus

I have an Android GS6 and am on Windows 10, and in the past, I would plug in the USB and be able to see the photos with little thumbnails.  Now, (the past few months) as the files become visible in the window manager, instead of thumbnails I'm seeing a weird default computer-ish icon for ALL the files in my DCIM folder except a dozen or so.

How can I tell if this is a virus?  I've tried searching, clearly my keywords aren't useful, as I'm getting results for things like pics disappearing in iCloud and restoring deleted pics.

[image: screenshot of what I see]

The pics aren't actually vanishing as they remain on my phone, but the window manager can't DO anything with them, can't open them, can't tell they are .jpg files...

I apologise in advance for this...if the photo uploads it's much easier to tell what I mean by looking at the pic.  Thank you!

Comment: It isn't a virus.

Comment: Could you clarify what I need to do then?  :-)  @music2myear

Comment: @Worthwelle, that worked for me.  Have a different problem now (Explorer just freezes) but the thumbnail issue is fixed.  If you'd like to recast this as an "Answer" I'll mark it solved.  And....thank you!!!  This was driving me nuts!

Comment: Rewrite your question. You are asking if it is a virus. The answer is that it isn't. We LIKE questions to change, to evolve as we explore what is and isn't a factor. So, evolve your question given this information.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a corrupt thumbnails cache. Try [the following](https://neosmart.net/wiki/clear-thumbnails-cache/amp/#Windows_10):

> To clear the thumbnails cache on a Windows 10 system, follow these instructions:
>
> 1. Open Windows Explorer
> 2. Go to the *View* tab
> 3. Select *Hidden items*, then select *Show selected items*
> 4. Navigate to `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`, where `C:\` is where you
>      installed Windows 10 and `User` is the username of your account profile. If Windows 10 was installed on `D:\` and your username is `Anna`, the path you need to navigate to is: `D:\Users\Anna\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer`
> 5. Select all files that begin with thumbcache
> 6. Right-click these files and click *Delete*
> 7. Empty the Recycle Bin